# How do you hide the Sale Ends column in Eventbrite?

Tags: eventbrite

We are currently a few days away from an event coming up for our university. The coordinators would like me to hide the Sale Ends column from our ticket sales on eventbrite. I have been searching, but dont see any solutions? Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When editing your event, you can click on a link titled "Timezone & Date Settings" in the "Date & Time" section, just below the Event name and location.  From there, you will have options to hide the start/end dates:

[image]